# Could not cast value of type '__NSCFString' (0x7fff87a89460) to 'NSArray' (0x7fff87a8a310)

Tags: swift

I'm extracting data from Mssql. I want to print the data I received from the database to tableview, but I get the error "Could not cast value of type '__NSCFString' (0x7fff87a89460) to 'NSArray' (0x7fff87a8a310)". I assign the data to the value variable. How can I solve the problem?

```
class MakaleController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    @IBOutlet var makaleTable: UITableView!
    var stringvalue: [String] = []
 override func viewDidLoad() {
           super.viewDidLoad()
        let client = SQLClient.sharedInstance()!
             client.connect("...") { success in
           client.execute("SELECT Email FROM ...", completion: { (_ results: ([Any]?)) in
                          for table in results as! [[[String:AnyObject]]] {
                              for row in table {
                                  for (columnName, value) in row {
                                    self.stringvalue = value as! [String]
                                  }
                              }
                          }
                          client.disconnect()
                      })
                  }
```

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

```
   let cell:UITableViewCell = self.makaleTable.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "makalecell") as! UITableViewCell


        cell.textLabel?.text = self.stringvalue[indexPath.row]

        return cell
    }
    }
```

Comment: No no I'm using sqlclient for the first time I don't know exactly how to pull the data @JoakimDanielson

Comment: `var stringvalue = ""` and `self.stringvalue = value as? String ?? ""`

Comment: This time I get the following error in the "cell.textLabel? .Text = self.stringvalue [indexPath.row]" line in tableview: "'subscript (_ :)' is unavailable: can't subscript the discussion

Answer (score 0):

May be problem is here

```
 self.stringvalue = value as! [String]
```

please do

```
print(type(of:value))
```

`value` is a `String` type

Do

```
self.stringvalue.append( value as! String )
```

Comment: output : __NSCFString

Comment: so it's not `[String]` then cast should be to `String`

Comment: error code: Cannot assign value of type 'String' to type '[String]' . Replace 'value as! String' with '[value as! String]'

Comment: yes it;s a workaround but you use it inside for loop so last value will be eventually

Comment: what should I do